Liya Zaurbekova, situation
https://www.themoscowtimes.com/2024/05/17/chechen-woman-fleeing-familys-death-threats-leaves-russia-official-says-a85147
https://youtu.be/lgDDp_eHk8E?si=5PooQI90FK5hji98
a very resonant phenomenon in Russia. How does Islam look at the fact that a girl is running away from her parents (hiding from them in the police icebox), and they are trying to bring her back against her will?

Not based on Islam at all but I cannot hold back a personal comment: I think Islam in Chechnya is heavily corrupted by Russian Foreign agents. May ALLAH open your eyes.

This needs more details, why should she run away at all?

Alhamdulillah,
Generally speaking, Islam places great emphasis on honoring, obeying and treating parents with utmost kindness and respect, unless they command something sinful. The Quran instructs believers not to say a word of disrespect to parents (Al Israa':23).
Parents have certain rights over their children in Islam, which include providing guidance, discipline and looking after their children's best interests, physically and spiritually.
Children are instructed to obey their parents as long as the parents' commands do not violate Islamic teachings.
In cases of disputes between children and parents, Islam encourages resolving them amicably through advice, patience, wisdom and involving respected third parties if needed.
If the daughter faces real harm, abuse or coercion from parents to do something impermissible, she is allowed to leave and remove herself from that harmful situation.
Regarding this specific scenario, there is not much information to go on at all but general advice would be to focus on:

Understanding the daughter's grievances through calm discussion.
Parents treating her kindly, avoiding coercion to do haram.
Seeking mediation and counseling from wise family/community members.
If abuse/coercion to commit haram is confirmed, authorities should get involved to protect the daughter's safety.

And Allah knows best!
